# Dependency Injection IApplicationEnvironment Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, config

The whole day I am trying to get this working.

I am doing a dependency injection via this code:

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnviroment appEnv)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Everytime when I am executing this code I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am really annoyed of that because I can't get it working and I have no clue about it. I am relatively new to Asp.Net and C# but this is how the tutorial said me to do. Does everyone know what my problem about the code is?

---

### Maybe this helps.

```
#if DEBUG
        services.AddScoped<IMailService, DebugMailService>();
#else
        services.AddScoped<IMailService, RealMailService>();
#endif
```

My Interface:

```
public interface IMailService
{
    bool SendMail(string to, string from, string subject, string body);
}
```

My DebugMailService

```
public class DebugMailService : IMailService
{
    public bool SendMail(string to, string from, string subject, string body)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Sending mail: To: {to}, Subject: {subject}");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you configuring the DI?  It looks like you don't have IApplicationEnvironment mapped to anything.

Comment: I added more code myabe this will help you? Sorry I am a beginner with C# @Paul Abbott

Comment: OK, where are you mapping IApplicationEnvironment, e.g. `services.AddScoped<IApplicationEnvironment, ApplicationEnvironment>();`

Comment: I don't have something like that. I just passed the IApplicationEnviroment via Dependency Injection. But I think the probelm is related to the IApplicationEnviroment  because if I delete it then it is not presenting the problem

Comment: I did some checking and it looks like this is part of ASP.NET 5/vNext, which is under a lot of flux since it is still pre-release software.  I would bet either the tutorial you are looking at is for a previous release candidate, or there's still some issues to work out, like https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3222

Comment: Thats so strange, I cheacked my version and the version of the tutorial and we are both at ASP.NET 5. I have no clue why it is not working at mine. But I could isolate the problem a bit. He is using the "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration" and if I include this into my project I can't apply the ".AddEnviromentVariables()" method. In order to do this I need the "using Microsoft.Extension.Configuration". Do you know the difference between the Extension and Framework??

Comment: As well I saw that his IntelliSense completed the IApplicationEnviroment automatically maybe due the framewrok he added. When I hover over it with my mouse I only get the option to generate a interface object.

Comment: It depends on exact version of ASP.NET you're using. If it is RC1 - then you don't need `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration` since it was replaced by `Microsoft.Extension.Configuration` in RC1. Otherwise you need first one and don't need second one. Also make sure you're not mixing different versions (betaX and rc1) of assemblies in your project.json file - this could lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Ah yes I am using rc1 in all my packages. But if I add the  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` then the Application knows about everything except the IApplicationEnviroment. Do you know how I add a package so it knows about it? Or did something change in rc1 with the SetBasePath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities it could be:

1. Your json schema in project.json is pointing to the wrong place. Mine is `http://json.schemastore.org/project`
2. Your intellisense might be giving problems. The usual visual studio restart works most times, but if that doesn't, stackoverflow has a lot of responses to fix that. Just search for it.

As you can see below intellisense works fine and finds `IApplicationEnvironment`, which exists in `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`.

[image: IApplicationEnvironment]

**However**, luckily in RC1, its no longer required to include `ApplicationBasePath` on `Configuration()`, which exists in `IApplicationEnvironment`. Meaning its optional to inject `IApplicationEnvironment` into `Startup` for your case. My sources: [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/88) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2990).

So you can just change your Startup method like this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build().ReloadOnChanged("appsettings.json");
}
```

Lastly, make sure you dont have any version mismatches, it will definitely causes issues if you include `beta8` with `rc1-final` packages in the same solution. Since you said you are new to asp.net and also the use of `config.json`, tells me you might be confusing beta versions with RC asp.net core releases. Even though you can name it whatever you want, default naming was changed to `appsettings.json`. So again, **make sure** your package versions in `project.json` file is on the same release.

I hope this helps.